# Accessing application context and bean from separate JVM?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on an application that launches several batch files, which themselves launch JVMs using Spring application contexts. The application I'm working on needs to be able to access the beans being created from the application contexts in these JVMs so that I can manipulate them.

From my application, I do have access to the name of the context file and the bean name. Is there a way I can access a reference to the beans created by these JVMs?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your beans and use JMX connector from your client application to access it. Here's the documentation for [Spring JMX.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jmx)

Comment: Refactoring how the beans are defined isn't really an option for the codebase I'm working with. I don't really need this functionality for very much, so the kind of refactoring I'd need to put in to use JMX wouldn't be worth the time. Unless there's another way, I'll have to think of some other solution. Thanks, though.

Comment: Spring by default doesn't expose the beans. You'll have to configure it to expose the beans. There are annotations that will help you achieve this. `@ManagedResource`, `@ManagedAttribute` etc on top of your class/method/property will expose the beans. Without touching it, I don't think there is elegant way as of now.

Answer (score 0):

How about spinning up a server on the target JVM where the Spring app runs on, that listens on some port XYZ. Then you can implement whatever logic you find appropriate to serve requests from connecting clients. This server itself can be managed as a Spring bean. So in essence it's like you're adding and "ear" to the JVM is ready to listen on. Details of how exactly this can be implemented depend on how Spring is configured on the target JVM(s).